# How to get separate input from multiple usb microphones

Tags: portaudio

I am using portaudio and trying to get input from two separate usb webcam microphones.

I connecting to two separate devices yet the data I get seems to me mixed (speaking into one microphone shows up in both outputs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad, my visualization  code had a bug